# Using *ngIf={{object.field}} is causing Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I got a mat-list and mat-list-item working and need to hide and show based on the value of different boolean types. In my data collection, I added a field to specified the name of the boolean for the *ngIf. When I render the UI, F12 shows me the following error

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>
> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("                   
>
>                                     <div [ERROR ->]*ngIf={{metricTotal.clause}}>
>                                     <div class="ng-container" *ngIf={{"): ng:///AppModule/SalesComponent.html@226:41
> Can't bind to '*ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
> ```

I can't use `ngIf` directly to the name of each actual `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use interpolation **`{{}}`** with *ngIf , remove the curly braces,

```
 <div *ngIf=metricTotal.clause>
```

Comment: then How can I set the ngIf to different class boolean with repeatative coding?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `{{}}` for `*ngIf` condition. It should be like:

```
<div *ngIf="condition">Content to render when condition is true.</div>
```

you can use it directly:

```
<div *ngIf="metricTotal.clause">
```

If it's in a `*ngFor` then try to use a function  in the component to return value:

Ex:

```
<div *ngIf="isDisplayed(metricTotal.clause)">
```

in your component, you can build your logic to return true or false based on `clause`:

```
isDisplayed(clauseValue): boolean {
// your logic to decide the display condition

return true; // or false as needed

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best approach, but I removed the interpolation which threw me off.

```
In the angular, I changed to *ngIf="getDataTypeName(item)"
```

In my ts code

```
getDataTypeName(clickItem: string) {
  if (clickItem == 'dataset1') {
  return true; }
  else if ...
}
```

Comment: what do you mean threw you off? and what you need, Did the answers below help?